# Where did Will end up in the last episode?

Tags: tv, shannara, shannara-chronicles

In the second season (and afaik, series) finale, Will is thought to have sacrificed his life to undo the warlock lord's corruption of the world- but near the end, when the elfstones glow in Mareth's hand she realizes Will is alive somewhere.

In the final scene Will wakes up lying in a bleak landscape with humanoid skeletons half-buried in the dirt around him and winged monsters flying in a black sky above- where is this place?

Comment: Sounds like the Forbidding, the prison the demons are kept in by the elves tree. I don't have a source though

Comment: Confirmed cancelled; https://screenrant.com/shannara-chronicles-season-3-cancellation-reason-news/